# Paper stopping in Printer - Java Print Issues

Tags: java, printing

This class is used to print out a file. I have a JButton(not shown in the code below) that runs this code and opens up a print dialog. However when I hit print it starts printing, but if the text doesn't take up the whole page it stops and won't eject it from the printer. Am I missing something that may be causing this issue?

```
try{
        FileInputStream textStream;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        textStream = new FileInputStream(testFileName);
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc test = new SimpleDoc(textStream, flavor, null);

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);

        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        if(services.length == 0){
            if(defaultService==null){
                System.out.println("NO PRINTERS");
            }else{
                DocPrintJob job = defaultService.createPrintJob();
                job.print(test, aset);
            }
        }else{

            PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, services, defaultService, flavor, aset);


            if(service != null){
                DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
                job.print(test, aset);
            }
        }

    }catch (IOException | PrintException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error message - either with the printer itself or the program? Any additional information in that regard could be helpful.

Comment: No there is no error message at all. It just stops in the printer. I went to print out something else(not from my program) and it started printing on the bottom of the rest of the page left in the printer.

Comment: I must say that is the strangest behavior for a printer to partake in that I've ever heard of. Do you have access to another printer or have a friend that could run the program through their own printer? This sounds like it could be a problem with the printer, not java.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank's for the help

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`javax.print` and your code work like this:

Read an `InputStream` (some file) of some (unspecified = `INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`) format and "submit" (`.print`) the PrintJob to the operating systems printer system.

Whats happens next totally depends on your operation systems setup like properly installed printer drivers and printer connectivity.

In your case the destination queue might not support the file format (aka PDL) you try to print. Even text based PDLs use [ESC sequences](http://www.undocprint.org/_media/formats/page_description_languages/hl-series_techreference_revc_oct1994.pdf) for printer control. Windows and Unix / Mac systems have different approaches. CUPS can handle PDLs like PDF or Postscript by default.

Once the job.print() method has ended it's up to the OS to deal with the print data. To track the issue you should check your OSs printer system. On Unix probably [CUPS](http://www.cups.org).